# Kotlin split() removing repetitive strings

Tags: kotlin, split

I was originally trying to remove special characters form a string eg:

- string: "aa..aa..aa...a."
- Expected output: ["..","..","..","."]

I was splitting the original string using:

```
var split_string: Set<String> = charsplit.split(re_di).toSet()
```

where re_di is the regrex containing the delimiter and charsplit is the input string

I am receiving output `["","..","."]`. According to the data and several other testing results I am assuming that the split function is deleting repetitive data. Can someone please provide insight on how can I record duplicated using split() in Kotlin

- string: "aa..aa..aa...a."
- Expected output: ["..","..","..","."]
- I am receiving output: ["","..","."]

Comment: I suspect the problem is with your regex. You might want to post that. By the way, if you format your code between backticks (`), using triple backticks (```) for code blocks, it makes everything much more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is how Set works. Since you use `.toSet()` you will always get distinct data. To get desired output you should use `.toList()`

```
var split_string: List<String> = charsplit.split(re_di).toList()
```

Comment: just FYI, `.split(...)` already returns a `List`, so `.toList()` isn't really needed